# What are the correct x264 settings to achieve the lowest latency possible?

Tags: video-streaming, h.264

I'm making a streaming system than consists of

1. backend - generates and encodes 1280x720@30fps with libx264 and sends NALUs to frontend over UDP
2. frontend - receives frames from backend, decodes with ffmpeg and draws on the screen

I'm trying to achieve the lowest latency possible.

- What is the lowest achievable latency?
- What are the correct settings for the encoder?
- What should I take into account?

Comment: See this link for inspiration http://forum.doom9.org/archive/index.php/t-164688.html

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing would be to set –intra-refresh –-tune zerolatency and set --vbv-bufsize to equal to you bitrate divided by framerate. Note that these settings will likely produce lower quality video due to lack for B frames, and other optimizations.

Comment: I still get latency ~200ms and can't find the reason.